# sqlite3: Unique constraint

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a new database with Table_A.

Table_A

id name    comments                key

1  peter   random string           1234

2  sam     random string           5678

This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_A (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
class TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
key INTEGER NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(name, key) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

Now when I try to insert elements to this table no duplicate entries are inserted which is expected because of

```
UNIQUE(name, key) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

But the id is incremented and I am not sure how to fix this.

Actual output:

```
Table_A
id  name    comments                key
1   peter   random string           1234
26  sam     random string           5678
75  john    random string           1478
```

Expected output:

```
Table_A
id  name    comments                key
1   peter   random string           1234
2  sam     random string            5678
3  john    random string            1478
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), you get autoincremented values without gaps for deleted entries when you drop the AUTOINCREMENT keyword.

Comment: +1. The important excerpt of that documentation: _"Note that "monotonically increasing" does not imply that the ROWID always increases by exactly one. One is the usual increment. However, if an insert fails due to (for example) a uniqueness constraint, the ROWID of the failed insertion attempt might not be reused on subsequent inserts, resulting in gaps in the ROWID sequence. AUTOINCREMENT guarantees that automatically chosen ROWIDs will be increasing but not that they will be sequential."_